# Using Interceptor instead of Lifecycle

Tags: hibernate, migration

I am working on a Java webapp (1.4) where we use Hibernate 2. We are going to upgrade to Hibernate 3 and since it is recommended in the migration guide to use Interceptor instead of Lifecycle (which is now deprecated), we are trying to make this change.
However, we noticed an important difference between these 2 interfaces about the onLoad(...) method:

- in Lifecycle, it is called after the object is loaded
- in Interceptor, it is called before the object is loaded

Some of our code do things that need the object to be loaded. Using Interceptor, the object is empty.
I looked at the other methods in Interceptor but nothing seems to fit. Any ideas?